# Run function on jquery knob release

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-knob

I have a form that calculates an estimate.  I want the sales person to be able to mark up the estimate, by a percentage using jquery-knob.  I have it all working, but I want to have the value change on release of the knob, or change for that matter, either one, so they don't have to hit the calculate button again.  I haven't been able to get query-knob to fire anything on release or change, I'm sure I am missing something very simple here, but it just escapes me.

Here is the input element itself:

```
<input type="number" name="adjust" id="adjust" value="100" data-min="75" data-max="125" data-step="2" class="dial notstored adjuster" data-width="150" data-cursor=true data-thickness=.4 data-fgColor="#1C5C67" data-inputColor="black" data-bgColor="#FBFBFB"/>
```

Here is are some of the calls I have tried, the first one not following the knob readme at all (edit: I have also tried wrapping these in document ready):

```
<script>
$("#adjust").change(function () {
                alert('monkey')
            });
</script>
```

And here is one using the knob documentation:

```
<script>
$("#adjust").knob({
                'release' : function () { alert('monkey'); }
            });
</script>
```

I've tried many other various incarnations of theses, but it would just make this post longer than it already is.  Thanks for any guidance.

EDIT: solved.  When you have multiple of these in a form and you call them based on class, but one should fire something on release, make sure it is called by ID and does not have the class.

Comment: Try wrapping your code in a DOM ready function `$(document).ready(function() { //your stuff });`

Comment: @tymeJV - Tried that, thanks though.  I am also testing all of this in a clean file, just to make sure there aren't any conflicts.

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/wewKx/ Make sure you have your imports correct and that your script is either in `$(document).ready(function() { }` or comes after the `input` element.

Comment: also all your attributes on your input should be in quotes, even if they are not string values.

Comment: @cfs Thank you.  I have about 8 of these things in a multipage form.  I was initializing them all based on class, but this one on id, though I still had the class in it, hence no fire...  I will fix my attributes.  Thank you again, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

sorry ! i see this in 2019 almost: 2020 ! :D
thanks Anthony Terrien !  **I really do not like spinners from  numeric input forms like many stuff doesn't work proper** !

well,this is my vision how these could replace spinners :
(**just when you place this code in a proper html doc just click / push inside to edit**)

```
    <div class="py-5 text-center pi-draggable" draggable="true">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="text" class="  " data-cursor="true" value="56" onfocus="thisknob(this);">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="text" class="  " data-cursor="true" value="56" onfocus="thisknob(this);">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="text" class="  " data-cursor="true" value="56" onfocus="thisknob(this);">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Knob/1.2.13/jquery.knob.min.js"> </script> <script>
    var current = null;

    function thisknob(what) {
      target = what;
      if (current != null) resetknob();
      current = $(what).knob({
        min: 0,
        max: 300,
        stopper: true,
        'release': function(v) {
          // console.log('da');
          resetknob();
        }
      });
    }

    function resetknob() {
      value0 = $(current[0]).find('input')[0].value;
      //console.log($(current[0]));
      $(current[0]).parent().html('<input type="text" class="  " data-cursor="true" value="' + value0 + '" onfocus="thisknob(this);" >');
      current = null;
    }
  </script>
```